# Print Two Different Text Alignment on same line in Android Bluetooth thermal printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, alignment

so we are currently developing this app which prints receipts via bluetooth. The process is working, but our only problem is we can't print the layout that we wanted.

We wanted to print in this way:

```
| ID Number:        123456789|
```

where the left fields are default, and the right fields are generated automatically.

We tried doing work arounds but it seems like the bluetooth printer only reads one text alignment.

Here's our current code:

```
 align=new byte[]{0x1B, 'a',0x00};     \\this is left alignment
 mmOutputStream.write(align);
 mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
 align=new byte[]{0x1B, 'a', 0x02};    \\this is right alignment
 mmOutputStream.write(align); 
 mmOutputStream.write(msg2.getBytes());
```

And the output would always be the alignment on top. For example when we set the top alignment on the left. It will just display like this:

```
| ID Number:123456789        |
```

I hope you could help us guys, we've been figuring this out about a week.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm resolve that with create function like this:

```
void writePrint(byte[] align, String msg){
    try {
        mmOutputStream.write(align);
        String space = "   ";
        int l = msg.length();
        if(l < 31){
            for(int x = 31-l; x >= 0; x--) {
                space = space+" ";
            }
        }
        msg = msg.replace(" : ", space);
        mmOutputStream.write( msg.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And we can use it:

```
writePrint( PRINT_CENTER, "| ID Number : 123456789 |");
```

Comment: what is 31 here?

Comment: 31 is length of one line from android device

Comment: Showing number format exception